# Vanilla JavaScript Drag And Drop - clone element

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, dom-events

How to edit this Javascript code to drag and element and leave a copy in the original container?

```
...

containers.forEach(container => {
    container.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const afterElement = getDragAfterElement(container, e.clientY)
        const draggable = document.querySelector('.dragging')
        if (afterElement == null) {
            container.appendChild(draggable)
        } else {
            container.insertBefore(draggable, afterElement)
        }
    })
})

function getDragAfterElement(container, y) {
    const draggableElements = [...container.querySelectorAll('.draggable:not(.dragging)')]

    return draggableElements.reduce((closest, child) => {
        const box = child.getBoundingClientRect()
        const offset = y - box.top - box.height / 2
        if (offset < 0 && offset > closest.offset) {
            return { offset: offset, element: child }
        } else {
            return closest
        }
    }, { offset: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY }).element
}
```

Everything is working, all that I need is to leave a copy of the dropped element.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to clone the draggable element. After that, in the drop event, you have to append your element.
in the case of using dragover, when you add an element, you have to remove it on dragleave event.

```
"use strict"
let currentWidget;
function dragAndDropInitilize() {


    var draggables = document.querySelectorAll("div[draggable='true'");
    var dragzones = document.querySelectorAll(".dragablezone");

    draggables.forEach(draggable => {
        draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
            var clone = draggable.cloneNode(true);
            clone.classList.add("dragging");
            currentWidget = clone;
        });

        draggable.addEventListener('dragend', () => {

            draggable.classList.remove('dragging');
        });
    });

    dragzones.forEach(zone => {
        zone.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const nextElement = getNextelement(zone, e.y);
            if (nextElement == null) {
                zone.appendChild(currentWidget);
            }
            else {
                zone.insertBefore(currentWidget, nextElement);
            }

        });
        zone.addEventListener('dragenter', () => {
            zone.classList.add('dragover');
        });
        zone.addEventListener('dragleave', () => {
            zone.classList.remove('dragover');
            zone.removeChild(currentWidget);
        });
        zone.addEventListener('drop', e => {
            e.target.classList.remove('dragover');
            currentWidget.classList.remove('dragging');

            const nextElement = getNextelement(zone, e.clientY);
            if (nextElement == null) {
                zone.appendChild(currentWidget);
            }
            else {
                zone.insertBefore(currentWidget, nextElement);
            }

        });

    });
}

function getNextelement(zone, y) {
    var widgets = [...zone.querySelectorAll('.widget:not(.dragging)')];
    return widgets.reduce((closest, child) => {
        const box = child.getBoundingClientRect();
        const offset = y - box.top - box.height / 2;

        if (offset < 0 && offset > closest.offset) {
            return { offset: offset, element: child };
        }
        else {
            return closest;
        }
    }, { offset: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY }).element;

}
```

Answer (score -3):

It won't work because of this function:

```
    function getDragAfterElement(container, y) {
    const draggableElements = [...container.querySelectorAll('.draggable:not(.dragging)')]

    return draggableElements.reduce((closest, child) => {
        const box = child.getBoundingClientRect()
        const offset = y - box.top - box.height / 2
        if (offset < 0 && offset > closest.offset) {
            return { offset: offset, element: child }
        } else {
            return closest
        }
    }, { offset: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY }).element
}
```

try with something else.

Comment: Please explain why "It won't work because of this function" and suggest a possible alternative instead of "try with something else". Otherwise, this is not a valid answer.